# Why do I get an ActionView::Template::Error only when trying to upload an App to Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My application works on my local server, but when I upload it to Heroku, I get a page that says: `"We're sorry, but something went wrong."`

When I look at the Heroku Logs, I see an error line:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (/app/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css has already been required)
```

What does this mean if my application works fine in my local environment?  Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot this?

For what it's worth, my gemfile looks like this:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.8'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.0.1'
gem 'json'
gem 'ruby-fs-stack'


group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.11.0'
end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '3.2.5'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'
  gem 'uglifier',     '1.2.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.2'

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.1.0'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
end
```

Here is the Heroku log:

```
2012-12-11T18:10:43+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML
2012-12-11T18:10:43+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (11.4ms)
2012-12-11T18:10:43+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 131ms
2012-12-11T18:10:43+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-12-11T18:10:43+00:00 app[web.1]:     9:    
2012-12-11T18:10:43+00:00 app[web.1]:     11:   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
2012-12-11T18:10:43+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (/app/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css has already been required):
2012-12-11T18:10:43+00:00 app[web.1]:     8:    <meta name="author" content="">
2012-12-11T18:10:43+00:00 app[web.1]:     12:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
2012-12-11T18:10:43+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-12-11T18:10:43+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:10:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__2962376498821052289_32805880'
2012-12-11T18:10:43+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-12-11T18:10:43+00:00 app[web.1]:     7:    <meta name="description" content="">
2012-12-11T18:10:43+00:00 app[web.1]:     13:   <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>
2012-12-11T18:10:43+00:00 app[web.1]:     10:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
2012-12-11T18:10:43+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=obscure-mesa-7065.herokuapp.com fwd=75.165.254.103 dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=1ms connect=4ms service=257ms status=500 bytes=643
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know why it works on localhost but it seems that you have a circular dependency.

Go to app/assets/stylesheets and check the headers of application.css.scss, and then the headers of all the files it requires to make sure that none of them references application.css.scss.

Comment: hmmm... I don't see any reference to application.css.scss, but I do have `@import "bootstrap";` at the top of one stylesheet. Could that be causing the problem?

Comment: It looks like two of my stylesheets were referencing `@import "bootstrap";`. When I removed one of the references, it works fine. Thanks for your help!