# How to not require application.css.scss twice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, sass

Just got done some basic styling for my app. Using Twitter Bootstrap.... App was deployed to Heroku and working but now with the Bootstrap styling updates I am getting this error:

ActionView::Template::Error (/app/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css has already been required):

Anyone have any ideas what this could be. Have been fussing around for a couple hours now. Have tried a bunch of stuff. Some of it mentioned here:

[Why do I get an ActionView::Template::Error only when trying to upload an App to Heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13826385/why-do-i-get-an-actionviewtemplateerror-only-when-trying-to-upload-an-app-to1)

```
2013-07-17T15:12:26.494137+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 71.203.124.202 at 2013-07-17 15:12:26 +0000
2013-07-17T15:12:27.403656+00:00 app[web.1]:     4:     %title
2013-07-17T15:12:27.403656+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-07-17T15:12:27.403656+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (/app/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css has already been required):
2013-07-17T15:12:27.403656+00:00 app[web.1]:     3:   %head                              
2013-07-17T15:12:27.403656+00:00 app[web.1]:     5:       Current Lines and Analysis
2013-07-17T15:12:27.403656+00:00 app[web.1]:     6:     = stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all"
2013-07-17T15:12:27.403656+00:00 app[web.1]:     7:     = javascript_include_tag "application"
2013-07-17T15:12:27.404086+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered shared/navigation/_main_nav.html.haml (1.4ms)
2013-07-17T15:12:27.403656+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/posts.html.haml:6:in `_app_views_layouts_posts_html_haml___3387163029388442478_46287060'
2013-07-17T15:12:27.403656+00:00 app[web.1]:     8:     = csrf_meta_tags                                          
2013-07-17T15:12:27.403656+00:00 app[web.1]:     9:     :javascript
2013-07-17T15:12:27.404086+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered shared/_events_sort_toggle.html.haml (1.0ms)
2013-07-17T15:12:27.404086+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered shared/_main_flash.html.haml (0.1ms)
2013-07-17T15:12:27.404086+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered shared/_header.html.haml (4.5ms)
2013-07-17T15:12:27.403892+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-07-17T15:12:27.403892+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-07-17T15:12:27.404086+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered shared/_events_sidebar.html.haml (22.6ms)
2013-07-17T15:12:27.404248+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 904ms
2013-07-17T15:12:27.404086+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PostsController#index as HTML
2013-07-17T15:12:27.404248+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/index.html.haml within layouts/posts (40.5ms)
2013-07-17T15:12:27.404086+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered shared/_posts_sort_toggle.html.haml (1.5ms)
2013-07-17T15:12:27.404086+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered shared/_posts_multi.html.haml (2.2ms)
2013-07-17T15:12:27.404086+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered shared/_hot-events-box.html.haml (2.0ms)
2013-07-17T15:12:27.404086+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered shared/_leagues_toggle.html.haml (2.6ms)
2013-07-17T15:12:27.404248+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered shared/_top_users_sidebar.html.haml (1.7ms)
2013-07-17T15:12:27.404215+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=www.webxxxxx.com fwd="xx.203.124.xxx" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=918ms status=500 bytes=643
```

---

application.css.scss file

---

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_self
 *= require bootstrap
 *= require_tree .
 */

@import "bootstrap";
```

---

When I take these 2 lines out of my posts layout the site renders but without style...

---

```
= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all"
= javascript_include_tag "application"
```

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Check to see if you have `application.css` file in you `app/assets/stylesheets` directory.  By default `rails` places the content of what you have in your `application.css.scss` in `application.css`.  You might have created this file and missed to remove the default `application.css`.

Comment: I added an image of the assets directory

Comment: The site does render when I remove these 2 lines in the layout for the controller... = stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" = javascript_include_tag "application" ... but without the style

Comment: Have you checked to see other files do not have reference to `application.css`?  Try removing the `*= require_tree .` to check this.

Comment: I see no reference to application.css.scss in any files in the stylesheets directory. *= require_tree . ...... do I get rid of this just in application.css.scss or in all files under stylesheets directory?

Comment: That line should just be in `application.css.scss`, do you have them in all other files as well?  If so remove that line from all other files and just keep it in `application.css.scss`.

Comment: *= require_tree . is in application.js. Is it ok there? It is not in any file in the stylesheet directory except application.css.scss.

Comment: Yes that's okay.  So basically what that line says is include all the files within the `app/assets/javascripts` if it's in `application.js` and all the files within the `app/assets/stylesheets` if it's in `application.css` or `application.css.scss`

Comment: Take a read at this section of asset_pipeline as well http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives.  When you read it pay attention to `//=` and `*=` closely.

Comment: Man... really stuck on this. It works locally but I get "Internal Server Error" when I deploy to Heroku. It is saying I have included application.css twice... is it because assets are pre-compiled or something?

Comment: @slindsey3000, we could discuss this more on chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33704/rails-heroku

Comment: It turns out that getting rid of require tree . did the trick. I use Rails_Admin gem... maybe a conflict in there. Thanks @vinodhikary for all your help.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps related to your problem, but if you use source control and you've done a merge in the past you'll have a stylesheet looking like application.css.orig which will be included with require_tree. I had this same error and by removing the *.orig files it resolved itself immediately.

Basically, anything named *.css.* could be wreaking havoc with Rails.

Answer (score 0):

I turns out that removing require_tree . and adding files individually did the trick. Maybe I have a conflict because I use rails_admin???

Putting this up for anyone else who runs across this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I fixed it by running "rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production " locally and then pushing back to heroku.